# How to make a CCSprite physics enabled

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

Im working on a iOS GAME.
Now I need to create a CCSprite in my function and want it to float into the sky.
Here is the code:

```
CCSprite *corpse =[[CCSprite alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"kid_dead.png"];
corpse.physicsBody.type=CCPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic;
corpse.physicsBody.allowsRotation=true;
corpse.physicsBody.affectedByGravity=false;
corpse.physicsBody.velocity=self.kid.physicsBody.velocity;
[self._physicsNode addChild:corpse];

corpse.physicsBody.velocity=CGPointMake(0.0f,10.0f);
```

However, it seems like the corpse appears like static and not physics-enabled.
Anyone can offer some suggestion? Many thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to create a physics body and assign it before changing any of its properties:

```
CCSprite *corpse = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"kid_dead.png"];
corpse.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRadius:10 andCenter:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

You find those functions in the [CCPhysicsBody class reference](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCPhysicsBody.html).